# constructor resolution, default constructors and ()

Tags: c++, constructor

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

 class A{
public:
    A(){
    cout << "Class A!";}
    };


 int main()
{
    A a();
}
```

the above code does not call the constructor `A :: A()` even though they have the same input parameters (none). however if, in the main function, I remove the parenthesis from 
        `A a();` 
it calls the constructor. 
so what is the difference between `A a;` and `A a();`

i believe the question here is very similar maybe even the same however if some could explain in simpler terms I would be very grateful.
[Do the parentheses after the type name make a difference with new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new)

would declaring `A a();` ever call a constructor, under any circumstances?

do parameterless constructors exist in c++, or is that the same as a default constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
A a();
```

you declare `a` as a function taking no arguments and returning an `A` object.